# Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler Issue for WFFM

Tags: wffm, upgrade

I am integrating update 1 of Sitecore 8.2. with WFFM and facing below error:

> **Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler class.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler class.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Exception: Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler class.]
>      Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Dependencies.DependenciesManager.Resolve(String path) +239
>      Sitecore.Form.Core.Ascx.Controls.SimpleForm..ctor() +23
>      Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SitecoreSimpleForm..ctor(Item item) +22
>      Sitecore.Form.Core.Renderings.FormRender.OnInit(EventArgs e) +412
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098

Comment: what version of WFFM do you have installed? There is a specific version of WFFM for Sitecore 8.1 Update 1

Comment: i have installed Web Forms for Marketers 8.2 rev. 161129

Comment: i think you need to use the wffm upgrade package from this link https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers/82/Web_Forms_For_Marketers_82_Initial_Version.aspx find the upgrades section and download that upgrade packages and follow this instructions https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/0FD6B6EC5E85457CA28FE93951BCD2AB.ashx this may help

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  Is there an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your working with Sitecore 8.2 your most likely building your pages in MVC.

Make sure you're not attempting to place the older "Web Forms" based WFFM control into an MVC page.

I recall getting a similar error after I made that mistake during installation testing.

```
Sitecore.Form.Core.Ascx.Controls.SimpleForm..ctor()
```